# Maximum difference between two elements in an array using single loop

Tags: c, arrays

How to find the maximum difference between two numbers in an array using single loop and single iteration?

Ex: Consider an array `A[20]={10,3,6,8,9,4,3}` How to find the maximum difference between two numbers in the array using single loop and single iteration?

Comment: Please show us your attempt at this.

Comment: By thinking hard, coming up with an algorithm, and then translating that to code. If the code doesn't work, feel free to post it but don't ask us to write it for you from scratch.

Comment: By maximum difference, you mean which number is the biggest? And also, why don't you try to code it yourself first?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as this is clearly a write my code request without any visible effort from user, not a _question_.

Comment: Can't find approach to this question

Comment: Sounds like a cool problem, good luck to solving it!

Comment: Do you mean maximum difference between _two consecutive_ elements, or the maximum difference between _any two_ elements?

Comment: maximum difference between any two elements in array

Answer (score 4):

To solve this problem in a single loop consider how the numbers `A` and `B` that produce maximal difference `A-B` influence the difference:

- The difference will be greater when you pick larger `A`, and
- The difference will be greater when you pick smaller `B`

Once you make this observation, it becomes clear that you are looking for the largest `A` and the smallest `B` in order to achieve the maximum difference. This can be done in a single loop in O(n) time and O(1) space.

Comment: can you please write code for it so that i can understand it well

Comment: @saikumarmylavarapu Finding min and max in a single loop is a trivial thing to code, what's there to not understand? You need to make an effort at coding this up, otherwise the whole exercise is not helpful.

Comment: finding min and max numbers in an array is easy but how to find max and min numbers in an array in single loop and single iteration..?

Comment: @saikumarmylavarapu I suggest giving it a try.